# Releasing HashMap key-value with null value for memory optimization

Tags: java, hashmap, garbage-collection

If I put null value to a HashMap key in Java, will that memory-related value could be released by GC, even if HashMap reference still alives?

**Update**:

Using `hmTest.remove(sKey);`

Was the better solution to me, because it releases enough memory, even using a little more CPU.

Comment: Yes, but it would be better to just `remove()` the key, so both the key *and* the value can be garbage-collected, not just the value.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! Using `remove()` the memory heap was relieved!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your question is, if you do:

```
HashMap<.....> map = ....
map.put(null, new Object())
```

And `GC` runs *and* `map` is alive : will this mean that the mapping : `null = new Object()` is now eligible for garbage collection? If so, the answer is no. That mapping `null = new Object()` is stored in a so called `Node` inside the `HashMap` and that has a strong reference to the `HashMap` instance itself.

That would be rather surprising for developers to find out that their `null` key and `new Object()` value are gone, when the `Map` is strongly reachable; without anyone explicitly call `remove`.